# "Your answer couldn't be submitted because you're not editing a good question"

Tags: bug, edits, mobile-web, wording

I was trying to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37732338/5958455) to replace a wrong tag when I got this notice:

> [image]

Emphasis on dialog content:

> Your **answer** couldn't be submitted ...
>
> ... see: How do I ask a good **question**?

But wait, I'm neither asking a question nor submitting an answer. I'm trying to **edit** a *question*, but the first line of the dialog reads *Your answer* ...

Shouldn't it at least begin with *Your question* ...?

Related: [Can't submit tag edits on mobile because of bad title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376205/5958455)

[wording](/questions/tagged/wording) [wording](/questions/tagged/wording) [wording](/questions/tagged/wording) [wording](/questions/tagged/wording) [wording](/questions/tagged/wording)

Comment: What's your question? It is in fact a terrible question title, and the question has been appropriately closed. What were you trying to edit? And how would your edit make the question become on-topic for SO?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am **editing** a question, but the first line of the dialog reads *Your **answer***.

Comment: So what is your answer to the question -- how *would* your edit make the question on-topic?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The question had a misused tag and I just wanted to replace it with the correct tag. Yes it's a retag edit.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that doesn't seem directly relevant. The bug that is being reported isn't dependent on on-topicness. If someone asked a question on a hunting site asked, "I tried to shoot a bear out of season and my gun jammed, why?", the fact that an offense was being committed is not *directly* related to the cause of the gun jam.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: and I disagree. The op attempted to edit a question that is over 2 years of age, and his problem likely stemmed from question title requirements having been changed in the intervening years. Since we're encouraged to make more than trivial edits, since the question is of low quality, why is it a bug for the system to require more substantial improvements from any edit?

Comment: Is this reporting  a bug that the message should have read "your ***question*** couldn't be submitted" (in other words, the message is using the wrong word) or is it reporting that a simple tag edit should not be looking at the content of the already existing question?

Comment: @JasonBassford I think it's very clear that this question is about the former (the latter is addressed in the related link at the end).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Whatever I was trying to edit is irrelevant to this question: it's about a wrong wording used in a dialog.

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ If the question were clear, there wouldn't be so many comments on the "wrong" topic or requests for clarification . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford because people don't look at tags... isn't the presence of [tag:wording] obvious?

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ No. Honestly, I had to read the question about three times before I realized you hadn't meant you'd typed "your answer" as the first two words of an attempted question title rename. "SE dialogue box uses the wrong word" and "when I try to do nothing more than change a tag" would make this much more obvious.

Comment: @JasonBassford I got you. Thanks for the explanation, I've edited it to reflect the changes.

Comment: May I echo Bassford's comment. I've seen this question since early this morning and only "now" have I understood what the real problem is. Luckily, I didn't waste a vote.

Comment: There are six tags with [wording]...are my eyes playing tricks on me? what has the question title (“Your answer couldn't be submitted because you're not editing a good question”) got to do with the wording of the message? You placed quotes around it, which suggests you are quoting from a source but you're not.